# Compiling c program with dependencies, h and h0 files

Tags: c, gcc, hfile

I am trying to compile the gjh solver - written in C - into an executable file in windows. It is available [on netlib](http://netlib.org/ampl/solvers/examples/index.html)

I downloaded the c file and am using gcc compiler via WinGW on windows' command prompt. Trying to compile the gjh.c file directly gave me an error that says:

```
gjh.c:33:21: fatal error: getstub.h: No such file or directory
 #include "getstub.h"
compilation terminated.
```

I assumed that compiling `gjh.c` requires the dependency `getstub.h`.

`getstub.h` is not the only dependency required, there are other dependencies, namely: `arith.h`, `asl.h`, `funcadd.h`, and `stdio1.h`. All of these files are available on the same link where I found `getstub.h`. However, `arith.h0` and `stdio1.h0` are available instead of `arith.h` and `stdio1.h`.

Are these files the same? I tried to rename the .h0 files to .h and tried to compile `gjh.c`, but I got this error:

> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Are the two files the same? If not, is there any way for me to compile the gjh solver successfully into an .exe?

Comment: There's a makefile for Microsoft Visual C++. I would go that route instead of struggling with GNU stuff in Microsoft environment.

Comment: Nice open source goo. You need to find the documentation listing what all modules do and how they depend on each other. Or if such documentation isn't available, prompt the "programmer" to finish their work on the project.

Answer (score 0):

If that's the only problem in compiling, try using the `-I` switch in gcc:

```
gcc -I/my/path/to/include/files -o gjh gjh.c
```

the -I switch hints to gcc where to find your `#include` files.

I am not sure about the `stdio1.h`. I think your approach to rename is OK but that reference to external functions such as `Sprintf`. You need to link with a library defining that. If you know where it comes from, use the `-L` and `-l` switch in gcc for that:

```
gcc -I/my/path/to/include/files -L/my/path/to/library -lnameoflibrary \
    -o gjh gjh.c
```